# CheckBox "Checked" value in GridView is always false

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, ispostback

I'm using a `checkbox` column in a `gridview` which is populated from a `SQL` database. A button below the `gridview` should retrieve the data of the rows whose `checkboxe's` have been checked. When I loop over all the rows `checkboxe's`, none of them has `checked==true` even though I have checked them all before clicking the button. Here is the `ASP.NET` code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and here is the button's action that loops over all the rows' checkboxes:

```
protected void GetSelectedRecords(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);               
            if (chkRow != null && chkRow.Checked) //chkRow.Checked is always "false" 
            {
                string name = row.Cells[2].Text;
            }
        }  
     }              
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Try this:- `row.FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox`

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried this one but didn't work either.

Comment: Can you post the complete code I mean including Mark-up? Something else must be happening cz your code looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for your concern; the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are binding your grid in `Page_Load`, Make sure you are not binding your grid outside of `if(!IsPostBack){}`. Otherwise you will loose the `checkboxe's` on each `postback` and therefore losing the status of `checkboxe's`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       //Bind Your Grid Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This way exactly the problem. Thank you very much.